WordPressのブロックテーマのテンプレートでページネーション
WordPressのブロックテーマのテンプレートでページネーションの
< 1 2 3 4 >
を実現したいです。
ブロックテーマでは基本的にhtmlのみですが、ページネーションを出力したり、細かく検索機能をカスタマイズする際のphpはどのように書けば良いのかご教示いただきたいです。

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
